# how to convert a String value 512m into integer value 512?

Tags: java

how to convert a String value 512m into integer value 512?
hi,
can you please help me.i have a string 512m that i need to convert it has interger 512

thanks in advance
String s = "512m";

Comment: i mean String s="512m";

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework

Comment: @zvdh: Homework isn't off-topic. Completely failing to make any effort, however, is frowned upon.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(value.substring(0, value.length() - 1)); thanks i did in this way

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, previously one of the flags was "too specific and  isn't useful" (or something like this). Now I'm not able to find this flag, what could you advise me to select as close reason? I think that problem described above is specific for author and won't be useful for another SO users.

Comment: @zvdh: I don't know of a current close reason that would fit this question. SO moved away from having "no effort" close reasons, as SE management felt they were abused (as indeed they frequently were).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you, I'll prefer just to downvote no-effort questions henceforth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replace("\\D", "");
```

will remove all non-digit characters from the string, then you can just parse it:

```
Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove string characters:

```
String str = "512m";
str = str.replace("X", "");
```

Convert string to int

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to extract the number characters (regex group). Then convert the extracted characters to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

replace all non digits to blank and parse it to an int:

```
    String str = "512m";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("\\D", ""));    

    System.out.println(i);
```